# T-SQL to XML to C# Back to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I'm very new to SQL Server, C# and such. But I'm learning each day, which is fun!

I need to take info from 2 tables in 2 different databases in SQL Server. Turn it into an `.xml` file, bubble sort it in C# and transfer it back into a 3rd database in SQL Server.

I have made the code to turn the tables into xml files, my question here is if I can make them into just ONE .xml file.

The code I've learned creates one for each table, so 2 tables from 2 databases gives me 4 .xml files.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Database1].[dbo].[Table_1]
ORDER BY NEWID()
FOR XML AUTO

SELECT *
FROM [Database1].[dbo].[Table_2]
ORDER BY NEWID()
FOR XML AUTO

SELECT *
FROM [Database2].[dbo].[Table_1]
FOR XML AUTO

SELECT *
FROM [Database2].[dbo].[Table_2]
FOR XML AUTO
```

After it's turned to an xml file I must put it in C# and bubble sort it into the 3rd database in SQL Server, as you can see I can at least take the data I want, but when it comes to C# and bubble sort it I'm completely lost. I've googled around but I'm having trouble understanding so I was hoping you guys could try and explain in a more easier way.

Comment: Hi Marik, welcome on SO. Please allow me one hint: You've got two question here: It's one principle on SO to keep *one issue in one question*. This makes it easier for follow users to find answers to their questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One part of your question was: How do I get 4 XML results into one:

These are 4 different calls, two against the current Db, two against another Db:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
FOR XML RAW('INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'),ROOT('CurrentDb')

SELECT TOP 3 * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
FOR XML RAW('INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS'),ROOT('CurrentDb')

SELECT TOP 3 * 
FROM OtherDb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
FOR XML RAW('INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'),ROOT('OtherDb')

SELECT TOP 3 * 
FROM OtherDb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
FOR XML RAW('INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS'),ROOT('OtherDb')
```

To get the same together in one, you just have to wrap this within an outer select. And be aware of the `,TYPE`...

Some explanation: If you write `SELECT * FROM xyz FOR XML RAW` you'll get an XML back. This is a full and complex structure but still a scalar value.

Write `SELECT (SELECT * FROM xyz FOR XML RAW) AS MyXML,'test' AS OtherColumn FROM SomeTable`. You'll get  your XML, but as *escaped* text representation. You must specify the `,TYPE` to get a *real XML* back.

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT TOP 3 * 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    FOR XML RAW('INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'),ROOT('CurrentDb'),TYPE
)
,(
    SELECT TOP 3 * 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    FOR XML RAW('INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS'),ROOT('CurrentDb'),TYPE
)
,(
    SELECT TOP 3 * 
    FROM OtherDb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    FOR XML RAW('INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'),ROOT('OtherDb'),TYPE
)
,(
    SELECT TOP 3 * 
    FROM OtherDb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    FOR XML RAW('INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS'),ROOT('OtherDb'),TYPE
)
FOR XML RAW
```

Comment: Could you explain abit more? I tested and it does what I want, but I don't exactly understand why it works still.

Comment: @Marik, Hi, I added some explanations... Clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the next steps 1) Connect to sql database in c# (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C) 2) Execute your sql queries in c# 3) Put queries into DataTable.( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx)